# Missing values in IF condition

Tags: spss

I am looking for IF condition syntax in SPSS. I have 2 variables, one is lfd and the other is lfd2:

```
lfd   lfd2   target_variable
14    14     14
.     15     15
18    18     18
12    12     12
.     16     16
```

Both are numeric variables. Wherever lfd is blank, I want data from the lfd2 variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention it so I'm assuming you want the data from lfd when it is not missing?
This should do it:

```
compute newvar=lfd.
if missing(lfd) newvar=lfd2.
```